# Question about authentication in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

We have ActiveMQ Artemis 2.26.0 which is configured for Active Directory domain authentication.

When a user is authenticated the role is assigned using group membership (`userRoleName="memberOf"`) or username (`userRoleName="sAMAccountName"`). Is it possible to grant authorizations using both username and groups to which user belongs to?

Currently I have a `login.config` which works differently for users in different organizational units of domain:

```
LDAPLogin {
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.LDAPLoginModule sufficient
     debug=true
     initialContextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
     ignorePartialResultException=true
     connectionURL="ldaps://domain-controller1:636 ldaps://domain-controller2:636"
     connectionUsername="bind_username"
     connectionPassword="bind_password"
     connectionProtocol="s"
     connectionTimeout="5000"
     readTimeout="5000"
     authentication=simple
     userBase="OU=OU_for_application_users,DC=company,DC=tld"
     userSearchMatching="(sAMAccountName={0})"
     userSearchSubtree=true
     userRoleName="sAMAccountName"
     ;
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.LDAPLoginModule sufficient
     debug=true
     initialContextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
     ignorePartialResultException=true
     connectionURL="ldaps://domain-controller1:636 ldaps://domain-controller2:636"
     connectionUsername="bind_username"
     connectionPassword="bind_password"
     connectionProtocol="s"
     connectionTimeout="5000"
     readTimeout="5000"
     authentication=simple
     userBase="OU=OU_for_team_users,DC=company,DC=tld"
     userSearchMatching="(sAMAccountName={0})"
     userSearchSubtree=true
     userRoleName="memberOf"
     roleName="CN"
     ;
};
```

User from `OU_for_application_users` gets one role which is equal to username, and user from `OU_for_team_users` gets roles from list of groups to which the user belongs to. Technically it is different types of users (special application accounts and personal user accounts).

Is it possible to create a `login.config` which assigns to user a list of roles which combine username and list of user groups? Or is there any other way to add authorizations which use both username and group of user?

Also I think if it is a good idea. In other brokers, for example IBM MQ, we can configure separate authorizations for users and for groups. In ActiveMQ Artemis we have only one "role" regardless of what it represents - username or group name.

Comment: Update: added one optional login module to the `login.config`, and it seems to work. It includes `userRoleName="memberOf" and `roleName="CN"` for application users. Needs some further testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis supports *roles* based access control. There is no option to configure authorization based on username.

The configuration of the `LDAPLoginModule` is limited to `userRoleName` when assigning roles. However, JAAS login modules are pluggable so you are free to write your own or contribute changes to `LDAPLoginModule` to support the behavior you want.